# List of VLOOKUP items

Tags: google-sheets

I have a ledger spreadsheet that contains name of people and sports that they practice, which is organized like this:

```
column A | column B | column C
John     | Soccer   | Q1/2021
John     | Soccer   | Q2/2021
Mary     | Swimming | Q1/2021
Mary     | Swimming | Q2/2021
Mary     | Swimming | Q3/2021
Mary     | Soccer   | Q3/2021
Joe      | Soccer   | Q2/2021
Joe      | Vaulting | Q2/2021
```

On a separate sheet, I have the unique list of persons and I want a formula to list the unique set of sports for each person

```
column A | column B
John     | Soccer
Mary     | Swimming, Soccer
Joe      | Soccer, Vaulting
```

With **VLOOKUP** I can choose the first entry, but I am having trouble google sheets generating the list of all sports as output.

Comment: Hi. Is there a particular reason why you've want to use `VLOOKUP`? It's probably not really the function of choice for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Tedinoz for pointing out to something quite similar to what I needed.

This solved my problem, a formula on spreadsheet 2, column B

`=join(", ",unique(query(Ledger!A:B,"SELECT B WHERE A='"&A2&"'")))`